# See how looks json

Tags: android

I have a app which is connected with web service. I send some data by Json:

```
            try {


            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("token", regId);
            jsonObject.put("appId", GlobalConfig.getAPPLICATION_ID());
            jsonObject.put("phoneId", 1);

            JSONArray jArrayParam = new JSONArray();
            jArrayParam.put(jsonObject);

            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
            nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Token",jArrayParam.toString()));

            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(GlobalConfig.getSendEmail());
              httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(
                        (GlobalConfig.getAuthString()).getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, HTTP.UTF_8));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request
            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }
```

How Can I see how looks this json? 
I want to server see something like this:

```
{"Token": [
{

"token": "asdasfasf",

"appId": 8.8,

"phoneId": 142.369,

}
```

Comment: see the json where? on your android client, or on the server?

Comment: your example json it not valid

Comment: i don't understand the question

Comment: @njzk2 : it's too easy he want to see jsonobject output how it's looking after creating

Comment: you have any issue with my answer? because you are using same code in your next question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13947885/look-my-json-in-web-service

Comment: no, no. Your code work great but i need to my json looks like in my second question. I don't know How I can check that.

Comment: @user1302569 : i'm trying to solve your next issue

Comment: Sorry. I had a nice party yesterday and I have some lags when I am thinking about my app :) Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create json object as:

```
 JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
 jsonObject.put("token", regId);
 jsonObject.put("appId", GlobalConfig.getAPPLICATION_ID());
 jsonObject.put("phoneId", 1);

 JSONArray jArrayParam = new JSONArray();
 jArrayParam.put(jsonObject);

 JSONObject finaljsonobj = new JSONObject();

 finaljsonobj.put("Token", jArrayParam);
```

Now `finaljsonobj` JSON Object look as:

```
{
  "Token": [
    {
      "token": "asdasfasf",
      "appId": 8.8,
      "phoneId": 142.369,

    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `JSON.stringify(json_object)`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your JSON is actually valid (It is not) and you have a perfectly functional JSONObject. If you want to see it in the console, you just have to do this:

```
System.out.println(myAwesomeJSONObject.toString(2));
```

That 1 refers to the number of indent spaces. I like it with 2 indent spaces, but that's a matter of personal taste and readability.