# Checking Json in a web service

Tags: android, json

I have a problem with json. 
I want my Json to look like:

```
 data={"phoneId":1,"token":"APA91bF2tN5g1TtULFE5tysRMAarygjX4w9hjTGCqT3SL-PwiMV6aqTtkV3lpqLkc7msVfEdTnyd_pJVFNMM_fjEbeVSuCjiNPVKx7p9sYC1DoWnuKUurt31E1yh2RDwl_oprfKxEF18PP6Q8dXHZe6FeflE3CIxBg","appId":5}
```

This is my post to web service:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
                     jsonObject.put("token", regId);
                     jsonObject.put("appId", GlobalConfig.getAPPLICATION_ID());
                     jsonObject.put("phoneId", 1);

                     JSONArray jArrayParam = new JSONArray();
                     jArrayParam.put(jsonObject);

                     JSONObject finaljsonobj = new JSONObject();

                     finaljsonobj.put("data", jArrayParam);

                System.out.println(jsonObject.toString());
                List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
                nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Token",jArrayParam.toString()));

                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(GlobalConfig.getSendEmail());
                  httppost.addHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + Base64.encodeToString(
                            (GlobalConfig.getAuthString()).getBytes(),Base64.NO_WRAP));
                httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePair, HTTP.UTF_8));

                // Execute HTTP Post Request
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

How can I check if my json looks like one in my example? I want to check how my json is post to webservice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try as:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
jsonObject.put("token", regId);
jsonObject.put("appId", GlobalConfig.getAPPLICATION_ID());
jsonObject.put("phoneId", 1);

System.out.println("data="+jsonObject.toString());
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePair = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
nameValuePair.add(new BasicNameValuePair("Token","data="+jsonObject.toString()));
```

this will create your JSON object as:

```
data={
  "phoneId": 1,
  "token": "token",
  "appId": 5
}
```

Answer (score 1):

U can create wrapper class for your JSONObject:

```
public class YourWrapperClassName{
    @SerializedName("phoneId")
    private int phoneId;
    @SerializedName("token")
    private String token;
    @SerializedName("appId")
    private int appId;
}
```

Prepare your JSON object and view in debug how it looks:

```
YourWrapperClassName testObj = new YourWrapperClassName();
// initialize testObj fields

Gson gson = new Gson();  // import com.google.gson.Gson; 
String result = gson.toJson(testObj); // put breakpoint here
```

Link for downloading Gson library - http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/downloads/list

Answer (score 0):

I think that your finaljsonobj have the structure:

```
{"data":[{"phoneId":1,"token":"APA91bF2tN5g1TtULFE5tysRMAarygjX4w9hjTGCqT3SL-PwiMV6aqTtkV3lpqLkc7msVfEdTnyd_pJVFNMM_fjEbeVSuCjiNPVKx7p9sYC1DoWnuKUurt31E1yh2RDwl_oprfKxEF18PP6Q8dXHZe6FeflE3CIxBg","appId":5}]}
```

The problem is the JSONArray, if you wnat to have the structure of:

```
{"data":{"phoneId":1,"token":"APA91bF2tN5g1TtULFE5tysRMAarygjX4w9hjTGCqT3SL-PwiMV6aqTtkV3lpqLkc7msVfEdTnyd_pJVFNMM_fjEbeVSuCjiNPVKx7p9sYC1DoWnuKUurt31E1yh2RDwl_oprfKxEF18PP6Q8dXHZe6FeflE3CIxBg","appId":5}}
```

Just delete jArrayParam and do:

```
finaljsonobj.put("data", jsonObject);
```